# Centos Stream 8 NetworkManager - Where is DHCP client lease data?

Tags: centos, networkmanager, dhcp

When using dhclient, the current lease info, including expiration time, is in `/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient.leases`, and contains something similar to

```
lease {
  interface "enp3s0";
  fixed-address [redacted];
  option subnet-mask 255.255.254.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 3523;
  option routers [redacted];
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 96.113.84.141;
  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1,75.75.75.75,75.75.76.76;
  option domain-search "[redacted]";
  option dhcp-renewal-time 2016;
  option broadcast-address 255.255.255.255;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 3073;
  option domain-name "hsd1.or.comcast.net.";
  renew 3 2022/06/22 23:59:57;
  rebind 4 2022/06/23 00:23:15;
  expire 4 2022/06/23 00:30:45;
}
```

However, my system uses NetworkManager which, based on my research, uses its own internal DHCP client.  Looking in `/var/lib/NetworkManager` I see

```
$ sudo ls  /var/lib/NetworkManager/
internal-79cbd87e-9d65-4aa4-8768-88b460fd372c-enp3s0.lease  NetworkManager-intern.conf  seen-bssids
internal-79cbd87e-9d65-4aa4-8768-88b460fd372c-ens1.lease    NetworkManager.state        timestamps
internal-bdaf2eb0-de2e-4573-a415-214629c7b757-enp3s0.lease  secret_key
```

which looks promising.  However, the lease files contain only the IP address.

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/internal-79cbd87e-9d65-4aa4-8768-88b460fd372c-enp3s0.lease
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=[redacted]
```

Simple question: Where does NetworkManager keep the lease data so it knows when it needs to renew the lease?

Comment: have you ever found the solution of this issues

Answer (score 3):

Seen [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/networkmanager-list@gnome.org/msg29020.html), newer versions of NetworkManager will expose this information in `/run/NetworkManager/devices/$IFINDEX`.  If you have an older version (or just prefer running programs to parsing files) you can interrogate NetworkManager for this information using

```bash
$ nmcli -f DHCP4 device show $IFNAME
```

where `$IFINDEX` is the numerical index NetworkManager has assigned to your interface and `$IFNAME` is its name.

(I suspect you already know this because the question on networkmanager-list had the same wording as here, but I doubt we'll be the last two people with this exact question)